# Почему хук вызывается 2 раза?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Имеется такой код:

```js
function MainPage() {


    let slider = React.createRef();
    let slideSpeed = 500;

    let [slidesCount, setSlidesCount] = useState(0);
    let [leftDragger, setLeftDragger] = useState(0);
    let [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);

   //Хук вызывается 2 раза
    useEffect(() => {
        setSlidesCount(document.querySelectorAll('.slick-list .slick-slide:not(.slick-cloned)').length)
        console.log(slidesCount) //Сначала выводит 0, потом 4
        
    }, [slidesCount]);
    


    let settings = {
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: slideSpeed,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        beforeChange: (currentSlide, nextSlide) => {
            setActiveSlide(nextSlide);
            console.log(leftDragger);

            if(activeSlide == 0) {
                setLeftDragger(100 / slidesCount * (activeSlide + 1) / 2 + "%");
            } else {
                setLeftDragger(20)
            }

    
        }
      };

    return(
        <div className="main-page">
            <section className="about">
               <Slider ref={slider} {...settings}>
               </Slider>
               <SliderNav slideSpeed={slideSpeed} sliderDOM={slider} />
            </section>
            <section className="remembers">
                
            </section>
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default MainPage;
```

useEffect вызывается 2 раза, сначала выводит 0 элементов (хотя их 4), а второй раз уже 4, почему так происходит и как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас `useEffect` сначала срабатывает на дефолтном значении, определенном в `let [slidesCount, setSlidesCount] = useState(0);`. При этом срабатывает `setSlidesCount(4)`, но так как `setSlidesCount` меняет `slidesCount` *асинхронно*, в первый раз вы видите в консоли 0. После того, как `setSlidesCount` все же поменял  `slidesCount` еще раз срабатывает useEffect, так как он забинжен на  `slidesCount` еще раз выполняется `setSlidesCount(4)` только на этот раз значение и так уже было 4. В консоли соответственно 4. Значение не изменилось, `useEffect` больше не выполняется.

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` сначала срабатывает на дефолтном значении, определенном в `let [foo, setFoo] = useState(0);`.

`useEffect` сработал, запустилось `setFoo(4); console.log(foo);`. `setFoo(4)` меняет значение асинхронно, так что получаем вывод `console.log(foo); // 0`;

`useEffect` вызывается при изменении `foo`. А значит как только обновится `foo` оно вызовется снова.

`setFoo(4)` отработал и изменил значение `foo`. Снова срабатывает `useEffect`.

Еще раз выполняется `setFoo(4)`, только на этот раз значение и так уже было 4. В консоли соответственно 4. Значение не изменилось, `useEffect` больше не выполняется.

Упрощенный ваш пример:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function MainPage() {
    let [foo, setFoo] = useState(0);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setFoo(4)
        console.log(foo) //Сначала выводит 0, потом 4
    }, [foo]);

    return(<div className="main-page"/>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainPage/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Лучше не менять состояние в `useEffect`, если он с ним связан.
Вот пример:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function MainPage() {
    let [foo, setFoo] = useState(0);

    React.useEffect(() => {});

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setFoo(foo + (foo < 100))
        console.log(foo)
    }, [foo]);

    return(<div className="main-page"/>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainPage/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```